# How can I get npmjs.com to show my README.md file?

Tags: npm

The [npm website for my package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@portal-payments/solana-wallet-names) is showing the following message:

> This package does not have a README. Add a README to your package so that users know how to get started.

[image]

But a README.md *does* exist in the package.
[My code has a `README.md` as shown on the npm website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@portal-payments/solana-wallet-names?activeTab=code), so npm is reporting the message incorrectly.

[image]

How can I get npmjs.com to show my README.md file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a caching issue. The file listing (which shows `README.md` existing) and the front page for the package (which shows the error about `README.md` missing) seem to update at different speeds. The cache updated within 24 hours.

There is [an open GitHob issue about npm.js incorrectly showing this warning](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3904).

Comment: PS. since I only checked after 24 hours, it would be useful if people commented how fast the cache updated for them - I suspect the cache updates more frequently than 24 hours.